# Using values in a generic list with wild cards

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make an abstract class that has a list of Objects of type T, that also has a function that takes a String value and a single Object of the same type T:

```java
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> {
    private String title;
    private List<T> dataRows;

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    };
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<T> getDataRows() {
        return dataRows;
    }

    public void setDataRows(List<T> dataRows) {
        this.dataRows = dataRows;
    }

    public abstract String getValueFromRow(String key, T dataRow);
}
```

Which I extend like so (using MyObj1, MyObj2, etc...):

```java
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyObj> {

    public String getValueFromRow(String key, MyObj dataRow) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I want to process different implementations of the `getValueFromRow()` method like so:

```java
public void doWork(MyAbstractClass<?> obj) {

    for (int i = 0; i < obj.getDataRows.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myKeys.size(); j++) {
            // This line does not work. I get an error saying this is an invalid type
            // even though getDataRows() is List<T> and the method requires type T
            String val = obj.getValueFromRow(myKeys.get(j), obj.getDataRows().get(i));
            doStuff(val);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use a value from the `List<T>` of objects in the method that requires an Object of type T I get the error: `Wrong Second Argument Type. Found '?', required '?'.` Where am I going wrong?

I have tried replacing the `<?>` with `<Object>` but then I get an error when trying to call the method:

```java
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setDataRows(data);
obj.setTitle("My Title");

//This is now the wrong input type when using <Object> rather than <?> in the service
myService.doWork(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `?`, you're telling the compiler that you don't care about the type and it doesn't matter. But the object cares and it matters as it has to ensure that the argument has the right type. Here is an analogous example of your problem:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    
    static class C<T> {
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<>();
        
        T get(int i) { return l.get(i); }
        void add(T t) { l.add(t); }
    }
    
    static void doThings(C<?> c) {
        c.add(c.get(0)); // 1
        
        // even clearer
        String s = c.get(0); // 2
        c.add(s);
        
        // doesn't matter
        Object o = c.get(0);
        c.add(o); // still an error
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C<String> c = new C<>();
        c.add("hello");
        doThings(c);
    }
}
```

At *1 is basically shown what you're doing. At *2 the problem gets clearer. You tell the compiler to not care about the type but it has to at *2 (and *1).

To solve this, you can make the method generic just like the class:

```java
    static <T> void doThings(C<T> c) {
        c.add(c.get(0));
        
        // works as T is known at compile-time
        T s = c.get(0);
        c.add(s);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without making the service class generic / a static method?

Comment: @grizzasd The `static` doesn't matter. It's just in my example. But you need to make this method generic.